# Nodemailer - Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have problem with nodemailer - I use it within Cloud Functions in Firebase and after data is created I send email confirmation (I use Blaze plan so that's not the problem). It was working for two days and suddenly this:

```
{ Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 554 5.7.1 <abc@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1425:28)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1378:30)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:709:51)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '554 5.7.1 <abc@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)',
  responseCode: 554,
  command: 'RCPT TO',
  rejected: [ 'another@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com' ],
  rejectedErrors: 
   [ { Error: Recipient command failed: 554 5.7.1 <another@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)
         at SMTPConnection._formatError (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
         at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1411:24)
         at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1378:30)
         at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
         at SMTPConnection._onData (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
         at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:709:51)
         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
         at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
         at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
         at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       code: 'EENVELOPE',
       response: '554 5.7.1 <another@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)',
       responseCode: 554,
       command: 'RCPT TO',
       recipient: 'another@gmail.com' },
     { Error: Recipient command failed: 554 5.7.1 <abc@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)
         at SMTPConnection._formatError (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
         at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1411:24)
         at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1378:30)
         at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
         at SMTPConnection._onData (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
         at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:709:51)
         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
         at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
         at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
         at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       code: 'EENVELOPE',
       response: '554 5.7.1 <abc@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)',
       responseCode: 554,
       command: 'RCPT TO',
       recipient: 'abc@gmail.com' } ] }
```

Also I get this error in Firebase console logs:`Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value`.

Here is the function:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => { // TODO should be returned
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }

            console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);

            //move it elsewhere - maybe HTTP trigger?
            return admin.database().ref('events/' + event.data.val().eventKey).remove();

        });
```

Comment: There are too many pieces in here, but the error message seems quite explicit: "Quota exceeded (number of mails in total)". So you're sending too many emails, which I can only imagine coming from nodemailer or your SMTP provider. That would also explain why it happens after a while, without any code changes.

Comment: This is because gmail has a capping of 500 emails in a day from a free account.https://group-mail.com/sending-email/email-send-limits-and-options/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm actually surprised because it's maybe 10 emails daily, not more.  That's why despite error message I asked here - because there is no way I exceed quota... really strange. Could it be something on mail provider side? Or how can I increase quota then to bypass this limit?

Comment: @AtulAgrawal I'm using private server for sending, not gmail. Gmail emails are recipients :)

Comment: It sounds like `554 5.7.1` is a "you're sending too many messages, we think you may be spam" from the receiving server or a relay server. See https://serversitters.com/how-to-correct-554-5-7-1-relay-access-denied-email-errors-and-prevent-them-in-the-future.html